# Smart-table AngularJS - Fixed Columns with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Is there a way or an additional plugin to fix columns in Smart table so on horizontal scroll the fixed columns don't go out of view.

Comment: My response on this thread can helps you with the fixed header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479587/make-table-100-with-fixed-header-with-smart-table-angular/29841787#29841787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue, and couldn't find any solution. Finally, I came up with the following [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/scTeynP69WDJ6z6tR69P).

The idea is to have two smart tables next to each other, both of them are set to `display: inline-table`. With some playing around overflow etc. I could make it work.